# new File(String url, String child) modify url

Tags: java, file, tomcat, url

I'm trying to create a new **File** passing a **url** as parent pathName and the fileName as child.

```
File savedFile = new File(Path.getPathDocumentAttach(), renameTo);
```

The path `Path.getPathDocumentAttach()` is correct, but the url *"https://...."* it's modified to *"https:/...."* (with only 1 "/").

So, when I pass `savedFile` to `FileItem.write(savedFile)` I got a **java.lang.NullPointerException**.

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to make it works?

ps. I want to save the file in the url I'm passing as first parameter (new File(**URL**(*it's a string*), "name"))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [new File(URL) exist? How can i achieve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62045821/new-fileurl-exist-how-can-i-achieve-this)

Comment: `File` is for handling files on the local filesystem, not for URLs.